# Binding data to multiple Pivot Items

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I'm learning how to develop a Windows Phone application so I started with a basic news application consuming data from a public API. I've gotten to the point of displaying a list of news articles (headline, byline, image) in a LongListSelector. Great. What I want to do next is allow the user to select what news sections they are interested in and then display that news content in multiple Pivot Items. I'm confident in being able to create a settings page where the user can pick their news sections and save that data.

The LongListSelector is currently bound to the DataContext in MainPage.xaml.

I don't really know how to proceed, so I'm looking for pointers on where to go from here. Perhaps a tutorial or sample project to look at?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to windows phone development too, so I am just sharing what I think would help. Not an expert by any means.

The longlistselector's data context should be a collection of data items, news article in this case. Each item's data context is different because you have to set up the itemsource property. That property gives each selection in the list an item from the collection. So if you query the user's selection's data context, you know what the user selected and go from there. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.

Comment: I currently have the LongListSelector setting all the article content correctly using DataContext = contents; where contents is a list of Article objects, and I'm using LongListSelector_SelectionChanged to pass an article ID to the ArticleView.xaml to view the article's content in full. What I have struggled with is: Having dynamically generated Pivot Items matching the user's chosen News Sections and having the News Sections ID passed into my GetContent method which is used to get 'contents' for the DataContext.

Comment: @WindowsPhoneWannabe To my understanding, you are fine with handling specific article but not the news section ID. These are similar concepts I think. If a user clicks on a news section, can you get the section ID too? If yes, then you can just pass that to whatever handler like you did with article ID. By the way, dynamically generated Pivot items are not common in windows phone, at least I haven't seen any. Use the Bing news app as a reference for some design tips.